# Can I share my Google Play "cloud" music with a family member?

Tags: google-play-music

I've uploaded all of our music to Google's "music in the cloud". I can play it on my Android phone (Droid X). I'd like my wife to be able to play it as well on her HTC Incredible).

Is this allowed?

How do I do it?

(One way would be for her to log in as me but that seems like it might cause problems with both of us logged into my account).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any music you purchase via Google Play Store or upload via Google Music Manager application is tied to whichever Google account you selected within the app under `Menu -> Settings -> Google Play account`.  Starting with Android 2.2 (a.k.a. Froyo) you can add multiple Google accounts on Android devices (phones, tablets, Google TVs, etc.)  Therefore if your relatives' handset/tablet supports multiple Google accounts, you can add your own account under `Settings -> Accounts & sync` on their device, and then within their Play Music app's settings you should be able to change the account to yours.  The music should then be available on their device to stream/download.

Comment: Isn't this option granting the family member/friend full access to the user's account?

Comment: @Dror: Yes, but it's the only way to do it. You can't share the music across accounts.

Comment: @Dror Alternatively, you can create a new Google account specifically for music purchases and add it to both your and your wife's phones. That way personal stuff like email and calendars can stay separate while music (and maybe books as well) can go on the shared account. Just don't forget to switch accounts in Play Store before buying music or books.

Answer (score 8):

Using the Google music uploader tool, you can also download all (Purchased only, I believe) music from any given Google Play Music account.  You could then switch accounts (or better yet, a different computer), and upload that music to a different Google Music account.

It would be a manual sync process, as the uploader tool won't automatically download purchased songs.

Comment: You can also download music you uploaded yourself but only up to 2 times, AFAIR.

Comment: The 2 download limit only applies if you download from the web client, the uploader tool does not have that restriction.  http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1233029

Comment: Is this practice allovied by the licence?

Comment: The original question was referring to music that the user uploaded themselves to the cloud, it's unclear, but I'd wager the new "Auto Matching" feature may further muddy the waters somewhat.  I'd call it "Questionable"

Answer (score 1):

@Brandorf - it's a good idea and I looked into it, but you **can not** share a single Google account among many users.  See here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33330?hl=en

Google Play **does** let you share Streaming Music that you subscribe too though.  AFAIK you can not share any purchased music, whether purchased from Google Play or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

These answers seem outdated.  In my experience you CAN now share playlists with anyone who is a Google Play member.  However, in my experience those playlists only work with songs that are available for purchase from Google Play.  Private or collectors music that I've uploaded to the Cloud myself seem to break the playlist even if I've made the playlist public.   They can see the list but when they try to play it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Two phones logged into the same account work OK in Play Music. I have set it up this way here. The only restriction is that only one can be playing, or have a track in the queue, at the same time. Clear the queue and the other phone can start playing.

Comment: The one-access limitation applies to Google home devices, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with the same issue. Wanting my wife to have the same access to my almost 4K songs without her having full access to my main Google account. Remember, Sharing your google password is a NO NO. Even with a family member. It give access to more than you can imagine. Web history, every photo you've taken, downloaded, or deleted. Web history, location history, and text, call, ability to track you via GPS, remote everything, and or wipe, lock, or completely erase.... and thats just your phone. Computer, Tablet, even track what you were doing on a friends computer even if your on the other side of the earth. If your logged in, more data is being collected than you think. Even if you think you know. And its all accessible. By you, Google, anyone who has your email address and password, and now (since a year ago bill passed) the Government. The ability to secretly track, take pics, video, and record audio, when your phone looks like its off. Unless your batteries off, its possible. Just knowing your email address, begins an array of info linking to info on you personally. Ever googled your email addresses? Scary. So with that being said, you shouldn't just log in with here phone, giving her access to your music because you cant separate everything else listed above. Its so scary, I dont even want to know my own Google Password. LOL. The only ways to share your music library is to...

A... Download your entire music library, log out, log in to her google music, then upload that folder. Note: It will be a large file. Even Zipped. (Ext. HD suggested) AND you can only download your music twice. EVER. one song or everything.

B... Upload your Music folder (once downloaded) to your Google Drive. Thats a Google Feature that you CAN SHARE with other Google accounts. Any type of files. Pictures, music, documents, or extensive that only special programs can open. From there, she could pick songs and play them one at a time, or down load them to her phone, or DL/UL to her Play music.

C..... I really like the shared Google account option. DL/Up load your music to a NEW Google account and share everything from Music, Books, and Emails. You can even pick what you want to share (sync) on your phone with that account, Giving access to Photos, and what ever. Just remember not to use the same password for the new account. (That make the whole point useless)

D..... What I have done so far is, download or buy music online with my computer, and upload it all to MY play music, KEEPING the music files on my Hard drive so, if she wants any music I have, I just log-in to her account, and upload it from the same source I uploaded to my account with.

F it..... I'm taking my music, and uploading it to my own server.Then I can do what I want with my music. So, neaaaa (Sticks tongue out)

It does stink that you cant simply share music like you can contacts, pics, or documents. Before the internet was dominated with massive servers, the web was mainly peer to peer. So with that being said, I support Torrent client software, and the index search engines that bring us all together. Long Live pirate Bay and its developers. (whom sit behind bars because other people share stuff with one another online) And these guys just made finding things to share simple, without uploading or sharing anything copyrighted themselves. Google Pirate bay justice for more info. You cant write your name on everything. I paid, Its mine, and I like to share. As long as you "Be Fair, when you Share"

Comment: This answer is quite rambly and almost half of it is irrelevant to the question. It's great that you have some good suggestions, but try to stay on topic. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so answers have to be focused and relevant.