# Can I share some Google stuff without sharing Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-play-music

I have a Nexus 4 and my wife just got an HTC One. I'd like to share accounts in Google play so that we can share app purchases. I'd also like to share Google music, contacts, and some other things. I don't want to share Gmail, Keep, and G+

I saw there were answers like this: [Can I share my Google Play "cloud" music with a family member?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20504/can-i-share-my-google-play-cloud-music-with-a-family-member)

But that was last updated a year ago. I'm hoping things have improved.

I understand I can turn off email syncing, but that doesn't stop someone from just going into the mailbox manually.

Creating a separate account for just music is cumbersome and is not an option. I'd rather just setup Spotify.

**EDIT to clarify**: The solution everyone gives is "new account." I'm asking: **Can you share Google Music and purchases and NOT share Gmail?**

Comment: Is there anything that makes this not a duplicate of the one you linked to aside from concerns that the answers may possibly be out of date? I guess that one doesn't cover anything aside from Music...but keep in mind that you can always start a bounty on an older question and select the "Current answers are outdated" reason.

Answer (score 1):

Any music you have *purchased* can be downloaded as MP3 files. Once downloaded, it can be uploaded to the Google Music service in another account. My wife and I do this with CDs we've purchased and ripped to MP3. IANAL, but since you are speaking of your wife, your property is shared and your music is owned by both of you.

This, however, does not work for the "All Access" features Google Music. If I understand the terms correctly, that account cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new Google account.
2. Transfer existing Play Store purchases from your personal account to this new account. You need to contact Google Support/Billing for that. Its not just theory.. I have seen such transfer.
3. Use this new Google account on multiple devices of family.

Comment: Since when is step 2 possible?

Comment: @Izzy You need to contact Google Support/Billing for that.

Comment: You should include that with your answer, Sachin. AFAIK it's not a trivial thing, and even Google Support doesn't do that easily as far as I have heard. In fact, I know of no case where a transfer was accomplished. Isn't that bound to certain conditions? If it were an every-day-issue, it would have been automated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot separate the GMAIL from the PLAYSTORE. You can let others use your google account to play music or download apps but they would also have access to GMAIL.